# Event-related EEG (epoch averaging) as a form of inter-harmonic bandstop filtering?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, bandpass, eeg, averaging, nonharmonic

There is a matter that comes to my mind from time to time, now I describe it in detail.
Anyway I am a first year PhD student, doing research in the field of cognitive neuroscience, but yet I only have tangential knowledge regarding EEG and also signal processing. I have read a few papers and even few chapters of Steven J. Luck's intro book about event-related potentials in EEG, but still I have not found a clear explanation about what exactly happens to a (single EEG channel) signal spectral content when the event-related averaging is done on it.

For those who are coming from other fields of science, I describe EEG and event-related averaging briefly:

Someone is sitting in the lab with EEG cap on their head. The cap has many electrodes touching the head of the participant via a conductive gel. There happens to be an electric potential difference between the individual electrodes of this grid around the head. This is picked up precisely by an amplifier device, and each of these electrode's signal gets recorded on a PC with ample sampling rate, e.g. 1kHz, to track what excitation levels the neuron populations are going through just under the skull bone. One recorded electrode/channel can be regarded as the potential difference from a chosen reference electrode (e.g. named "Cz") and the one in question, sample over time.

But let's say we are not recording the basic activity of the brain, instead we are trying to get to know something about what happens inside it when it is processing something specific. So, while the recording is on, the participant is doing a task on another computer, where for example they are told to memorize words that show up on the screen periodically. E.g. there appears a word on the center of the screen every 4 seconds (plus-minus some minimal intentional jitter, let's say 0.1 seconds), and the person is instructed to pay attention to them.

When we are doing an event-related analysis on the recorded brain signal, here for simplicity pick the signal recording of one electrode, and slice the signal up to little sections (epochs or sweeps) that are depicting the neural responses to those exact stimuli (events) we flashed on the screen during the experiment. If we want to know the typical response to the stimuli we presented, we can just average these epochs samplewise, where the beginning of each sweep is aligned to the onset of the stimuli (hence the name event-related averaging). So differences between the epochs will cancel out each other, and irregular noise content will converge to a minimum, given an ample number of sweeps taken into the averaging procedure.

The interesting part:

But wait: if the stimuli were rhythmically presented... even if there was a little jitter in them... then the actual content of the whole recording (regarding that electrode we are interested in) should contain the event-related information squeezed into certain bands of the signal spectrum, correct? The stimuli appeared with a period of 4+-0.1 seconds, so it should be represented in 0.25 Hz (0.243-0.256 Hz) + its harmonics in the signal.

Why do not we first filter the signal using multiple band-stop filters that remove any spectral content between the harmonics of interest, and only then would we slice up the signal to epochs and perform the event-related averaging?
My guess would be that the output of this procedure would have a greater amplitude, and probably the averaging step itself would be less affected by noise. Has anyone tried it before? (Calling out for people better into EEG for their opinion:)

But on the other hand, I guess the event-related averaging step itself should act as a multi-harmonic "filter", if I understand it correctly. It should attenuate any frequencies that are non periodic to the "sweep length" we are using for slicing up the signal for averaging.
Is there any book or paper covering what exactly event-related averaging does to a signal's spectral content? I am open to any interesting suggestions.

And how could pre-filtering the whole signal and then performing the event-related averaging improve the quality of an event-related signal? If we stop very wide bands of frequency between the harmonics of interest, then I guess we also cut important information out too... but if we only carve out a little but between harmonics, then there is not much effect I suppose. I guess the band-stop filters could be designed carefully to preserve the most of our periodic component, but still reduce nonperiodic content.. How can one do that?
I suppose there are many "fuzzy" tradeoffs here. (So funnily the harmonics are not a noise here but the thing we are really going after.)

I would be really interested in a novel way of improving event-related signal averaging via some kind of harmonic filtering, but at his point I am just undereducated in this field to try this out myself.

I am really new to DSP, and not coming from electrical engineering background, so please pardon if I am wrong or asking something too basic. Also, if anyone would like to play around with signals, you can just message me, and we could collaborate on something together.

Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: A lot of questions and space for subjective discussions. I would really recommend to collect some data and do some signal processing (e.g. have look at the Matlab toolboxes like EEGLAB or FIELDTRIP, also check the tutorials there). Regarding the experiment do something easy, like voluntary button presses (see Bereitschaftsfeld) or reaction time measurements. Here you can collect experience regarding the time based characteristics of electro physiological signals and frequency based characteristics (e.g. BPs vs ERDs).

Comment: Designing an experiment with reproducible brain activity is already challenging enough, once you manage this, you can check all your other hypothesis regarding signal processing